# VB.NET 3D graphics to 2D graphics how?

Tags: vb.net, matrix, 3d, 2d, converters

i need to convert 3d image to 2d image for my project.

I have this parameters:

> Length, width, Depth (dont know if i had used the right terms for this, but those values were given)

i also have x,y,z rotation.

most angles are divisible of 90, and some are 0. 
for me, that means it would be easier because they are quadrant angles.
but putting them into code gave me a head ache

most of the shapes i had are all basic one (ex. cylinder, rectangle)

any thoughts?

**what do i want to achieve:**

i just want it to be on orthographic view.
for example the cylinder, in one kind of view
(i dont know what to rotate with those 3 axis)
it could be just a circle,(top view?)
or just a simple rectangle,(side view/front?)

Comment: You need to be more specific. What data do you have? What do these parameters represent? What do you want to achieve? I guess it has something to do with projecting the 3D scene onto a 2D plane? What characteristics should this projection have? Should it be a perspective or orthographic projection?

Comment: yeah orthographic! thats it i just want the 3d shape to be on orthographic view

Comment: Then just take two of the three point coordinates. Which ones depend on the rotation. You might also want to scale and translate the resulting point based on your viewport.

Comment: thats exactly what im doing, yet on some of the given shapes, i have
x=y=z=0 so then i dont know what kind of view is it? also if they have all the same value or all of those have values, thats what confused me

Comment: As I said, you need to be more specific about the meaning of your parameters. Their type would be a good starting point.

Comment: im not quite familiar of your term "type" here sir, what do you mean by type?

Comment: Is it a scalar number, is it a vector, a matrix, a quaternion?

Comment: I dont know any of those, im sorry. what i do have is that the professor gave me one xyz coordinate(which is the startpoint), then the length, depth and width, also the x-rotation, y-rotation, and z-rotation. 

for keeping the shape on the panel, he thought me how to use >> to Matrix.Translate(), scale(),Rotate()
thats all he gave me.

Comment: Then you should learn the basics. StackOverflow is for specific questions, not for solving complete problems.